# How to prevent an user from sending messages to a group, but keep receiving messages from that group (read only)?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm using ejabberd 20.03 and the MucSub approach.

I tried to set affiliation = 'none' but the user can still send messages to the muc. Details:

ejabberd.yml:

```
...
modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban:
    c2s_auth_ban_lifetime: 10
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_query_users: false
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: true
      persistent: true
      public: false
      public_list: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false
```

Room Settings:

```
[{title,<<"500">>},
 {description,<<"500">>},
 {allow_change_subj,false},
 {allow_query_users,false},
 {allow_private_messages,false},
 {allow_private_messages_from_visitors,anyone},
 {allow_visitor_status,true},
 {allow_visitor_nickchange,true},
 {public,false},
 {public_list,false},
 {persistent,true},
 {moderated,true},
 {members_by_default,true},
 {members_only,true},
 {allow_user_invites,false},
 {password_protected,true},
 {captcha_protected,false},
 {password,<<"_500_">>},
 {anonymous,false},
 {logging,false},
 {max_users,200},
 {allow_voice_requests,true},
 {allow_subscription,true},
 {mam,true},
 {presence_broadcast,[moderator,participant,visitor]},
 {voice_request_min_interval,1800},
 {vcard,<<"
<vCard
    xmlns='vcard-temp'>
    <TITLE>Room Title</TITLE>
    <DESC>Room Description</DESC>
</vCard>">>},
 {vcard_xupdate,<<>>},
 {pubsub,<<>>},
 {lang,<<"en">>},
 {captcha_whitelist,[]},
 {affiliations,[{{<<"21112">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<>>},
                 {admin,<<>>}},
                {{<<"21247">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<>>},
                 {member,<<>>}},
                {{<<"21966">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<>>},
                 {member,<<>>}},
                {{<<"admin">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<>>},
                 {owner,<<>>}}]},
 {subject,[]},
 {subject_author,<<>>}]
```

I want user 21112 (room admin) to be able to set user 21247 (room member) in a state that prevents 21247 from sending messages to the room, but 21247 can still receive messages from the room. I tried:

1. Logged in with user 21112 and sent the following stanza:

```
<iq from="21112@domain.com/14965894906297405984175442" id="revoke_voice_c4ec85d0-7f14-11ea-8f19-77e4dd9aaad8" to="500@conference.domain.com" type="set"
    xmlns="jabber:client">
    <query
        xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin">
        <item nick="21247" role="visitor"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

and received an error:

```
<iq
    xmlns='jabber:client' xml:lang='en'
    to='21112@domain.com/14965894906297405984175442'
    from='500@conference.domain.com'
    type='error'
    id='revoke_voice_c4ec85d0-7f14-11ea-8f19-77e4dd9aaad8'>
    <query
        xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
        <item nick='21247' role='visitor'/>
    </query>
    <error code='405' type='cancel'>
        <not-allowed
            xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
            <text xml:lang='en'
                xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Changing role/affiliation is not allowed
            </text>
        </error>
    </iq>
```

I don't know why the error above is being returned. I've read the room configs and also the MucSub approach and I'm wondering if this is because of the MucSub implementation. I don't know. Then I just set the user 21247 affiliation to 'none', but still he is being able to send message to the room. The stanzas:

```
<iq from="21112@domain.com/14965894906297405984175442" 
    id="change_affiliation" 
    to="500@conference.domain.com" 
    type="set"
    xmlns="jabber:client">
    <query
        xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin">
        <item affiliation="none" jid="21247@domain.com" nick="21247"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

```
<iq
    xmlns='jabber:client' 
    xml:lang='en' 
    to='21112@domain.com/14965894906297405984175442' 
    from='500@conference.domain.com' 
    type='result' 
    id='change_affiliation'/>
```

In my understanding, since I set affiliation = 'none', I expected user 21247 not be able to send messages to the room, but can still receive new messages because he is a subscriber of the room (MucSub). Does anyone have ideas to achieve my goal?

Comment: I tried to set affiliation = 'none' <--- and where did you configure that?

Comment: I should edit the question with way more details. Doing it now.

Comment: @Badlop, I set the affiliation sending a stanza in conformance with Section 9.5 of XEP-0045.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, I see what you mean. You're right, with current MucSub implementation, there is not way to restrict a subscriber from sending messages to the room.

I've filled an issue explaining the case and providing a patch. With that patch, there's a room configuration that allows subscribers to receive messages but not sending them.

In case you are able to apply the patch, compile and install ejabberd:
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/3222

Comment: Thanks, I will try it! It is a good chance for me to grasp ejabberd source code and workflow. For now (urgency needs), I'm gonna block it on the client.